# Checking the datatype in every line in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, types

I want to know how it is possible to check what type of data (*integer*/*char*) the first letter in every line of an `inputfile` is.
I wasn't able to find something which answered my question, especially because I didn't know how I'm supposed to search after this.

For example in my `inputfile` is built like this:

```
Birthdate;Name
19920711;John
19801106;Alex
19950327;Sam
```

Now I just want to filter out the dates without the names and the headline. How is that possible?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Char.IsDigit` and or `Char.IsLetter`

for example:

```
Using sr As New StreamReader("c:\myfile")
        Do Until sr.EndOfStream
            Dim line = sr.ReadLine
            If line.Length > 0 Then
                If Char.IsLetter(line(0)) Then
                    Debug.WriteLine("First char is a letter")
                ElseIf Char.IsNumber(line(0)) Then
                    Debug.WriteLine("First char is a number")
                End If
            End If
        Loop
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following LINQ queries that uses `Char.IsDigit` and `DateTime.TryParseExact`:

```
var linesWithoutHeader = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Select(line => line.Trim())
    .SkipWhile(line => line.Length == 0 || !Char.IsDigit(line[0]));

DateTime birthDate = DateTime.MinValue;
List<DateTime> birthDateList = linesWithoutHeader
    .Where(line => line.Contains(';'))
    .Select(line => line.Remove(line.IndexOf(';')))
    .Where(dateStr => DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, "yyyyMMdd", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out birthDate))
    .Select(dateStr => birthDate)
    .ToList();
```